# Doubt regarding Michaelson Morley experiment

Tags: special-relativity

In Michaelson Morley experiment, when the ray of light reaches the glass slab inclined at 45° to the horizontal, it should be reflected vertically (90° to horizontal by basic geometry and law of reflection of light) but my textbook and class notes suggest that the light ray will be reflected at an acute angle to the horizontal. Am i missing something? Is the glass slab not kept at 45° to the horizontal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: An analogy to facilitate understanding : https://youtu.be/UGTmOCJ0NKI

Answer (score 0):

The different angle of reflection is due to the motion of the experimental apparatus through the luminiferous ether that light propagates through. In the mirror's rest frame, the light does reflect at 90 degrees. But, in the ether's frame, the mirror is moving and the light retains a component of velocity to the right equal to the speed of the mirror through the either (this is a Galilean transformation from the mirror's rest frame to the ether's rest frame). The motion through the either is provided by Earth's motion around the Sun.

Because of this change of direction, the light travels a different distance than the light in the perpendicular arm. This difference would be detected when the interferometer is rotated in the changing pattern of interference fringes when the light is recombined.

All of the above assumes the existence of the luminiferous ether through which light actually travels at $c$, the speed of light from Maxwell's equations. If an observer is moving through this either at some velocity, they would see light traveling at a different speed, much like riding in a faster car can make a slower car look like it's moving backwards. The fact that no change in the interference fringes were observed is important evidence of the non-existence of that either.